# Classic ASP connection works; .Net fails. Why?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis

This works in a Classic ASP Web site:

```
sConnString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=MySerer;Initial Catalog=MyDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
```

In a .Net web site, the following connection string gets a "Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'" error.

```
<add name="Production"  
     connectionString="Data Source=MyServer;Initial Catalog=MyDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Both run in the same Application Pool on IIS, and both sites are set to use the same Admin user to connect, as set under Basic Settings.

Seems that, though the .Net site runs as an Admin, it fails to pass that along to the SQL Server. Not only that, if I hardcode the login/password into the connection string, it returns the same error about anonymous login.

What's the deal?

Comment: you should provide the `Exception` message to see what happend, and why it failed

Comment: Please don't ever set up a web site using an administrative account.  You should use a separate service account with minimal access that is configured as the app pool identity that has access to the DB.

Comment: I removed my answer as the credentials I was speaking of, passed by IIS, to the SQL Server connection via the trusted connection is the credentials set up on the application pool.  Based on this, can you show a screenshot of the actual application pool configuration and the fact that the application pool is being used by the site that cannot connect?

Comment: Can you also share your web.config?  Do you have this enabled?
`<authentication mode="Windows">`  Throwing darts at a dartboard unless you can share some more details.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I had more than one problem. The login issue was resolved when I moved the app to its own Application Pool and set the Identity of the pool to an actual admin account. (I'm open to using a non-admin account; just needed to identify/solve the problem first.)

The other issue was some missing views and stored procs in the DB the DotNet site was supposed to query. Yes, Classic ASP could connect to that and another database, but connectivity was all I tested with Classic ASP, not actually performing the desired query. The DotNet site could connect to and query the DB that had the views and stored procs, but gave a 404 error when trying to query the DB that lacked those objects.

I can't say I'm totally clear on things, because the DotNet site sometimes could 
 get data from the DB with the objects even before moving it to its own Application Pool, and sometimes not. At least  I'm up and running. I will continue to experiment.